# Testing whether a number is pentagonal : comparison between two formulas

Tags: combinatorics

I'm programmer by trade but starting to get interested in math in my spare time.  I decided to learn the basics by working my way through the problems at Project Euler.

On [this](https://projecteuler.net/problem=44) problem I needed a function to check if a number was a pentagonal determined by the formula:

$$p_n=\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}$$

So I went about creating a function that accepts *Pn* and returns *n* and came up with:

$$n= \left\lceil{\frac{\sqrt{2P_n}}{\sqrt{3}}}\right\rceil$$

Or in JavaScript for the inquisitive:

```
let n = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Pn * 2) / Math.sqrt(3));
```

I tested it and it checked out. I went online to see if others are using this formula for finding *n* but it turns out another method is widely used:

$$n=\frac{\sqrt{24P_n+1}+1}{6}$$

My formula and this one appear to agree for positive integers.

Is my own formula something interesting or something most mathematicians would consider, obvious, pointless or otherwise uninteresting? If so, why? I found it pretty much by observing outputted values at different stages of working through the top formula and reasoning out something that worked in reverse then testing it.

Is there a better or more formal approach for finding such a formula (the inverse function, right)? Also, how do I go about proving (edit: or disproving) that my formula works for all positive integers of *Pn*?

Comment: To put it in simple words, you are asking if the equation $\left\lceil{\frac{\sqrt{2\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}}}{\sqrt{3}}}\right\rceil = \frac{\sqrt{24\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}+1}+1}{6}$ is true for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks for clarifying the core of the question. I'd also like to have the other parts answered, since I am learning from basics here and would like a bit of exposition.

Comment: btw, I have been working on an interesting example of use of pentagonal numbers:(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it in simple words, you are asking if the following equation is true for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$\left\lceil{\frac{\sqrt{2\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}}}{\sqrt{3}}}\right\rceil=\frac{\sqrt{24\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}+1}+1}{6}$$

---

Let's simplify this equation a bit:

$$\left\lceil{\frac{\sqrt{n(3n-1)}}{\sqrt{3}}}\right\rceil=\frac{\sqrt{12n(3n-1)+1}+1}{6}$$

---

And a bit more:

$$\left\lceil{\sqrt{\frac{n(3n-1)}{3}}}\right\rceil=\frac{\sqrt{12n(3n-1)+1}+1}{6}$$

---

At this point, note that we can get rid of the $\lceil\dots\rceil$ by adding $\frac{n}{3}$ to the expression inside the $\sqrt\dots$:

$$\color\red{\left\lceil{\sqrt{\frac{n(3n-1)}{3}}}\right\rceil=\sqrt{\frac{n(3n-1)}{3}+\frac{n}{3}}}$$

---

So the original equation becomes:

$$\sqrt{\frac{n(3n-1)}{3}+\frac{n}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{12n(3n-1)+1}+1}{6}$$

---

Or simply:

$$n=\frac{\sqrt{12n(3n-1)+1}+1}{6}$$

---

Multiply by $6$ each side of the equation:

$$6n=\sqrt{12n(3n-1)+1}+1$$

---

Subtract $1$ from each side of the equation:

$$6n-1=\sqrt{12n(3n-1)+1}$$

---

Raise to the power of $2$ each side of the equation:

$$(6n-1)^2=12n(3n-1)+1$$

---

Simplify it, and Voilà:

$$36n^2-12n+1=36n^2-12n+1$$

---

Please note that the equation marked red is not necessarily true for $n<1$.

Comment: I think you're looking for french.stackexchange.com/questions/398/what-are-the-informal-uses-of-voilà

Comment: @nij If you add `http://` at the beginning of the link in your comment, it should become "clickable".

Comment: @Nij: Thanks, found it already :)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I tried, and for the second time today, missed the edit window by about three seconds. Bleh. It's resolved for Barak Manos anyhow.

Comment: @barakmanos thanks for stepping through this (I'm having fun).

Comment: @Fergal: You're welcome :)

Comment: @barakmanos Everything makes sense to me except the step where the ceiling is removed by inserting $\frac{n}{3}$. How does this work?

Comment: @Fergal: It rounds up the original expression inside the $\sqrt{\dots}$ to the nearest square (which is equivalent to taking the ceiling of the $\sqrt{\dots}$ of the original expression).

Comment: @barakmanos this make total sense to me now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, the "correct one" (i.e. the one I'd recommend using and the one I would look for if I did the problem by myself) is the one you found on the internet. You get it by applying the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to the equation $$\frac{3n^2-n}2-p_n=0$$

The reason why $$\left\lceil\sqrt{\frac23 y}\,\right\rceil=\frac{\sqrt{24y+1}+1}{6}$$ *whenever $y$ is a pentagonal number* (if it isn't, then the RHS is not a positive integer) is that, with some algebraic manipulation, $$\frac{\sqrt{24y+1}+1}{6}-\sqrt{\frac23y}=\color{blue}{\frac16}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{36\left(\sqrt{\frac23 y+\frac1{36}}+\sqrt{\frac23y}\right)}}$$

Which is very close to $\dfrac16<1$ as $y$ grows. Moreover, the $36$ in the second denominator dumps the value of the red fraction for the first integer values of $y$. Putting all together, you can infer that, for $y\ge1$, $$\frac{\sqrt{24y+1}+1}{6}-\frac13< \sqrt{\frac23 y}<\frac{\sqrt{24y+1}+1}{6}$$

So, when $\frac{\sqrt{24y+1}+1}{6}$ is an integer, the ceiling gives the correct rounding.

Comment: Very good solution (+1)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, but now that I'm re-reading it, I made an unnecessary observation on the difference being $<\frac13$ (everything would have worked just fine, as long as it remains $<1$).

Comment: What does "desume" mean?

Comment: @bof Nothing, but it looks like an Italian synonim of the verb "to infer". :D

Comment: @G.Sassatelli thank you for a great answer. Can you also explain why the other formula I provided is incorrect?

Comment: @Fergal It depends on your algorithm. If your method to check if $y$ is penthagona is calculating an approximate value of $n(y)$ and check afterwards if $y=\frac{n(y)(3n(y)-1)}{2}$, then your formula should work too. Fact is that the reason why your integer approximation of the quadratic formula does not fail for small values of $y$ is fortuituous.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli you're quite right. I just did a bit of testing here and my formula starts to breakdown at $10^{67}$. So it would appear to be fortuitous in the extreme.